# Configure Hive remote metastore

Tags: hive, metastore

In the book Hadoop: The Definitive Guide, there is some content about the Hive remote metastore as below:

"Going a step further, there’s another metastore configuration called a remote metastore,
where one or more metastore servers run in separate processes to the Hive service.
This brings better manageability and security because the database tier can be completely
firewalled off, and the clients no longer need the database credentials."

Does anyone know what is the meaning of the above paragraph? Why "the database tier can be completely
firewalled off, and the clients no longer need the database credentials"?

Comment: You start a separate service called Metastore; the Metastore config contains the connection params to the database (a JDBC URL). Hive "clients" -- i.e. either Hive CLI (fat client) or HiveServer2 (JDBC gateway service) -- only have the connection params to the Metastore (a Thrift URL) and don't care about which kind of database runs under the covers.

Comment: Additionally, you can set up High Availability for the Metastore service (look at the Hadoop docs), independently from the High Availability at DB level (depends on which kind of DB you run).

Comment: Does the database tier include metastore server and mysql database? If so, is this the reason that the database tier can be completely firewalled off? For example, Hive client is on one machine and the database tier is in another, so there is a firewall between them, right?

Comment: The database is a database is a database. The Metastore would act as the "app" tier when using the 3-tier architecture concept.

Comment: The real point is: if you already have an Enterprise-grade pool of database servers (jerks use MySQL, serious guys use PostgreSQL, Yahoo! even uses Oracle) then you can just plug your Metastore service / Oozie service / Hue service to this pool.